# Formating issue when trying to use Png files for background wrapper

Tags: css, background, png

Hoping someone can help me out as I'm still pretty new to the whole web design thing. I'm using CSS to create a container wrapper. As you can see from the code I have a bottom, top and center image. When I was using JPEG images everything lined up correctly, however I needed to switch to PNG image files (to take advantage of transparency) and now the top and bottom sections of the wrapper are offset.

****Here is a live link: storrepictures.weebly.com/projects.html**

-Please find an image of the resulting problem here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjKsc.png
-This is how it looks when I use JPEGs instead of PNGs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhRTI.png

Here is my CSS code:

```
#wrapper {
    background: url(containerbg.png) center repeat-y;
    }

#wrappertop{
    background: url(containertop.png) top center no-repeat;
}

#wrappertbtm{
    background: url(containerbtm.png) bottom center no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 65px;
}
```

And here is the body portion of the HTML file:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="wrappertop">
        <div id="wrappertbtm">
        <div id="container">

        <div id="header">
            <div id="headerleft">{logo max-height="60"}</div>
            <div id="navigation">{menu}</div>        
        </div>      

        <div id="content">{content}
            <div id="footer">{footer}

            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Show us a reproducible example (your code and images in full?). Just changing background image will not alter the structure in anyway. Possibly that your PNGs are misaligned/different compared to the JPGs.

Comment: Live link: storrepictures.weebly.com/projects.html

Answer (score 1):

check height add width of jpeg and png..
may be both are different.
I am not sure but i think you can solve your problem by giving them same height and width..

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Here is a link to the site: http://storrepictures.weebly.com/projects.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your PNG images are not sliced properly check it the exact width & height of that.
Whereas they are PNG or JPEG they will come at their exact position if they sliced properly so the problem in not transparency the problem can be improper slicing of image....

And if you will give us the live demo than we would be able to see deeply the exact bugs..

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Here is a link to the site: http://storrepictures.weebly.com/projects.html. The dimensions of the PNG files are the same as the JPEG files so I'm not sure what the issue might be. Is there a special way to save the PNG files?